# compatibility DAKeyboard in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, uikeyboard

i'm using `DAKeyboard` in my app , since iOS 9 many app like `Viber` and ... problem with panning gesture to dismiss keyboard with this component.
[DAKeyboard iOS 9 support](https://github.com/danielamitay/DAKeyboardControl/issues/95)

a person write a code for finding keyboard in iOS 9 and it's working good in portrait.

**Problem**

but many problem will happen in `Landscape` mode.
anybody know how we can fix it ?

```
-(UIView*) findInputSetHostView {
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 9.0 && [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ) {
    for(UIWindow* window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
        if([window isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIRemoteKeyboardWindow")])
            for(UIView* subView in window.subviews)
                if([subView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIInputSetHostView")])
                    for(UIView* subsubView in subView.subviews)
                        if([subsubView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIInputSetHostView")])
                            return subsubView;
} else
    return self.keyboardActiveInput.inputAccessoryView.superview;
   return nil;
}
```

**UPDATE**

only for preventing bad behavior in landscape ,  i have checked  the orientation in my code